# Operator "&" cannot be applied to byte, int, boolean

Tags: java, bit, bit-shift

Upon my previous question about how to compare if combined bits contain a specific bit I am running into this error.

```
    int flag1 = 1 << 0;
    int flag4 = 1 << 5;

    int combined = flag1 | flag4;

    if (combined & flag1 == flag1) // <-- Operator & cannot be applied to int, boolean
```

If I cast the flags to byte the error replaces `int` with `byte`.

Comment: Oh, yet another Java operator precedence question... it is indeed confusing to me too! (of course it's still better than PHP `?:` :P)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The compiler sees the binary operator `&` in your `if` statement, treats it as logical AND (since it expects an expression that returns a `boolean`), and checks the types of the arguments.

It encounters one `int` argument - `combined` - and one `boolean` argument - `flag1 == flag1`. Since it expects two `boolean` arguments (the `&` operator cannot be applied to an `int` and a `boolean`), it gives an error.

Add parentheses in order for the operators to be evaluated in the desired order :

```
if ((combined & flag1 ) == flag1)
```

Comment: Thanks, lol I tried to edit your post since I edited my question. But right after you updated ;). `AOE` should be either `flag1` or `flag4`. In my previous question everyone was giving me the answer without parentheses, I wonder why...

Comment: @MennoGouw Yep, I noticed your edit and added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for a very well explained answer. I am new to bit comparing and operations but I understand now.